# How Do I Execute An Executable File Through CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to execute an .exe file through CMD but I don't know what command I'd do to launch it.  The only thing I can find is "How to execute .sh files on linux" but that's not what I want.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Linux `./program.exe`   ?   Windows `program.exe`

Comment: Just enter **the name of the exe file with .exe** at the end (**the absolute path** or at least the full name if you are in the correct directory)

Comment: Seriously?  It's that easy?  Alright!  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the executable for your program is "My Program" in directory "c:\My Directory" then to execute that program within a batch file, use

```
"C:\My Directory\My Program"
```

or

```
"C:\My Directory\My Program.exe"
```

or

```
START "" "C:\My Directory\My Program"
```

or equally

```
START "" "C:\My Directory\My Program.exe"
```

Use the `START` version if you want your batch to continue to the next line once it has started the program.

The `""` in the `start` version is the `window title`. You can place any window title you want within those quotes, but should not omit that `"titling"` pair.

Answer (score 1):

Just type:

```
pushd THIS IS THE PATH TO YOUR FILE
```

This changes the directory.

then type the name of the exe file

```
myfile.exe
```

This is an example:

```
pushd C:\folder
myfile.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `program.exe` is in the current working directory:

**Linux** `./program.exe`

**Windows** `program.exe`

*Specifying the absolute path always works.*

Answer (score 0):

Just enter **the name of the exe file with .exe** at the end *(**the absolute path** or at least the full name if you are in the correct directory)*